# C++ operator overloading causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading, libstdc++, g++4.8

below is the code which is giving segmentation fault for I don't know what reason. In an attempt to overload ^ operator, I am getting segmentation fault.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class bigint {

    public:

    char val[1000000];
    int msdindex;
    bool iszero;

    bigint( int i ) {
        if( i == 0 )
            iszero = true;
        else {
            iszero = false;
            msdindex = -1;
            while( i > 0 ) {
                msdindex++;
                val[ msdindex ] = i % 10;
                i /= 10;
            }
        }
    }

    bigint( const bigint& bi ) {
        msdindex = bi.msdindex;
        iszero = bi.iszero;
        for( int i = 0; i <= msdindex; i++ )
            val[i] = bi.val[i];
    }

};

bigint operator^( bigint k, int n ) {

    if( n == 1 )
        return bigint(k);

    bigint half = k^(n/2);

    return half;

}

int main()
{
    bigint bi = bigint( 999 );
    bigint di = bi ^ 4;
    return 0;
}
```

Segmentation fault is in the overloaded function ^ and I am clueless of the reason. gdb says this.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in 
>       from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
>   ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000000400749 in operator^(bigint, int) ()

Please help.

Comment: Please compile with -g, use gdb, and debug and see what your problem is.  I suspect that are not running an ordinary C++ program ,but some sort of python embedding, but you haven't revealed that. Does your operator work in a plain old C++ main method in a plain old C++ program?

Comment: Can you try with a smaller `val`? In your version, each `bigint` object takes up 1MB of space. *And* your operator takes one by value. *And* creates an internal copy. Perhaps you're running out of stack space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running out of memory, due to which you program crashes everytime. Reducing the status allocation of char in bigint to a smaller value will work fine.
Or use dynamic memory allocation in case you want huge char array, that will solve your problem.
Hope this helps.

```
class bigint {

    public:

    char *val;//[1000000];
    int msdindex;
    bool iszero;

    bigint( int i ) {
        if( i == 0 )
            iszero = true;
        else {
            iszero = false;
            msdindex = -1;
            val = new char[1000000];
            while( i > 0 ) {
                msdindex++;
                val[ msdindex ] = i % 10;
                i /= 10;
            }
        }
    }

    bigint( const bigint& bi ) {
        msdindex = bi.msdindex;
        iszero = bi.iszero;
        val = new char[1000000];
        for( int i = 0; i <= msdindex; i++ )
            val[i] = bi.val[i];
    }

};
```

Don't forget to write destructor for this to deallocate this dynamically allocated memory. Cheers.

Comment: "Don't forget to write destructor for this to deallocate..." *and* a copy constructor *and* a copy assignment operator. Or just use `std::vector` which already encapsulates all of this.

Comment: @Angew w.r.t. this question, copy constructor is already written, i don't see use of copy assignment operator. Btw, vector is certainly a better option.

Comment: Sorry, missed the copy ctor (somehow :-/ ). Still, the class would be broken without the corresponding assignment op ("Rule of Three").